# Using isDate return true vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I'm using `isDate()` Method in .NET. It returns invalid result. Why "AD05AD09" is read as date. following is the code i'm using. Please give me proper reason for this

```
    Dim value As String
    value = "AD05AD09"
    If IsDate(value) Then
        Dim oDate As Date
        oDate = CDate(value)
        MsgBox(Format(oDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
    Else
        MsgBox("a")
    End If
```

Comment: Generally, prefer [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `IsDate` is from the VB Runtime library which was mostly designed to support upgrading pre-.NET VB code. Thus retaining all of the quirks of the functions from that era.

Comment: even the `cDate` converts that to a date '05-09-2015'??

Comment: @akhilkumar yes, it returns a date. Try to copy the code.

Comment: ya i have done that...but did you notice? it doesnot work for every string you specify but only specific format.dont know whether the format you specified is a valid dateformat? just try passing some word or anything,it wil not work.

Comment: @akhilkumar if you change those letter, it will return an error. But that string is a user input as code in the database.

Comment: ya wierd....cant find a reason for that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As writtern in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> IsDate returns True if Expression is of the Date Data Type or can be converted to Date; otherwise, it returns False.

But you should go for the common ways, which are `DateTime.Parse`, `DateTime.ParseExact`, `Convert.ToDateTime` and more.

See this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) example:

```
Dim dateValue As Date
Dim dateString As String = "2/16/2008" 

Try
  dateValue = Date.Parse(dateString)
  Console.WriteLine("'{0}' converted to {1}.", dateString, dateValue)
Catch e As FormatException
  Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", dateString)
End Try
```

Comment: Thank you, but still return date for this string "AD05AD09"

Comment: Try: `DateTime.ParseExact` or `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Comment: And why is it that one should go for more common ways? I use functions like CDate, CInt and CStr all the time, because they are more intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

It is counted as a date because the first "AD" like said in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anno_Domini, AD is placed before the year, but because the 05 is not 4 digit but 2 digit, the functions treat it as the month. The second AD counts as a valid delimiter in the date like in "12AD12AD2008" is 12/12/2008.

So,

```
CDate("AD05AD09") '= 05/09
CDate("10AD10AD2000") '=10/10/2000
```

and so on.

But BC doesn't work, because BC can't be stored in a date, since you can't store negative years...